# mongo DB geoNear aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, aggregation-framework

I wonder if the ***geoNear*** query is similar to the ***geoNear*** operator in the new aggregation  framework? (performance aspect)

and if not what is the difference and which is better..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **geoNear** query uses a cursor and iterates over the index on demand, whereas the aggregation operator **geoNear** builds up the result in memory. Speed wise there is not going to be much of a difference, but memory wise you'd likely be better off using the query operator **geoNear**. If you don't need many documents than the difference is negligible.

**geoNear** (aggregation) does have the possibility to also add the distance to the returned document, something that the query operator doesn't support.